# Using Global Exception Handlers vs Local

Tags: c#, exception, networking, windows-phone

I have a windows phone app that makes web request. Each time I make a web request I have to handle network exceptions.

```
try
{
   string testString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   ex.Message == "net_http_message_not_success_statuscode"
}
```

Would it make more sense to have a global exception handler instead of having to write this code all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your calls funnel up to single location and the actual point of the exception isn't important, then a global exception handler would be just fine.

If you need to do some special handling closer to the point of the exception, then you'll need to keep the local exception handlers on each call.